# Using Aggregate and group by on spark Dataset api

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

```
    JavaRDD<Person> prdd = sc.textFile("c:\\fls\\people.txt").map(
          new Function<String, Person>() {
                public Person call(String line) throws Exception {
                  String[] parts = line.split(",");
                  Person person = new Person();
                  person.setName(parts[0]);
                  person.setAge(Integer.parseInt(parts[1].trim()));
                 person.setSal(Integer.parseInt(parts[2].trim()));
                  return person;
                }
              });

       RDD<Person>personRDD =  prdd.toRDD(prdd);
       Dataset<Person> dss= sqlContext.createDataset(personRDD ,               Encoders.bean(Person.class));
   GroupedDataset<Row, Person> dq=dss.groupBy(new Column("name"));
```

I have to calculate sum of age and salary group by name on the dataset.
Please help how to query dataset ? I tried using GroupedDataset but don't know how to proceed with it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can register the JavaRDD **prdd** as a table and then used in SQL statements

`DataFrame schemaPeople = sqlContext.createDataFrame(prdd, Person.class);
schemaPeople.registerTempTable("people");

// SQL can be run over RDDs that have been registered as tables.

DataFrame teenagers = sqlContext.sql("SELECT sum(age),sum(salary) FROM people group by name)

// The results of SQL queries are DataFrames and support all the normal RDD operations.`

Read more : http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#running-sql-queries-programmatically

Comment: Please help me understand  if i use this code then i am using dataframe , but i want to achieve it using dataset. am i missing anything ?